# What saves the session? NSURLRequest or NSURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

What saves the session? NSURLRequest or NSURLConnection? My app logs into my website with an NSURLConnection but needs NSURLRequest. What saves the session that I make when the login is successful? NSURLRequest or NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. NSURLRequest describes something to get from a remote host. NSURLConnection is an object whose job it is to send the message in an NSURLRequest to a remote server, and get a response. There's no session data kept by either.